# Django to PostgreSQL : Error loading psycopg2

Tags: django, postgresql, 64-bit, debian, psycopg2

Trying to `runserver` with `db['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.psycopg2'` I got :

```
[...]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/psycopg2-2.4.4-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/psycopg2-2.4.4-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4_64
```

with `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'` I got :

```
[...]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 24, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/psycopg2-2.4.4-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4_64
```

And I shouldn't use psycopg with Python >2.6, right ?

Any help on how to do make this work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try make a clean slate. Prepare separated virtualenv directory.

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv  # if you don't have it yet 
virtualenv /some/dir/
```

Activate virtualenv

```
source /some/dir/bin/activate
```

Prepare django and psycopg2 and whatever other libraries you use

```
pip install psycopg2 django # possibly other libraries
```

And then move to your project directory (this with manage.py), make sure project is within PYTHONPATH and try `./manage.py runserver` again.

Comment: Since my knowledge increased since I wrote this answer, now I would strongly advice to make familiar with virtualenvwrapper library: https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. It's easier to manager virtualenvs through it when you do initial setup.

Answer (score 1):

Your installation is broken. Maybe you run a 32bit python but the library is for 64bit.

I run psycopg2 with Python2.7 without problems.